# Doing a certain action based on the name of a file in a folder

Tags: applescript

I'm making a script to sort out my desktop. For example, if I save a file as "English Questions.docx", the script would pick up the word "English" in its name and move it to my "English" folder. So I need to know:

1. How to find the names of all the files on my desktop
2. How to move those files to a certain folder based on their name

Thanks.

Comment: To be able to answer, there are few more details to be provided : 1) are you always, and only looking for the first word in the name of your file ? 2) where the "English" folder could be found ? in your Document folder ? anywhere including any sub-sub folder ? 3) what if there is no existing folder matching the first word (if no "English" folder exists !) ?

Comment: No, any word in the name my file. My "English" folder is a subfolder of my "School" folder (on my desktop). Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the script bellow answers your problem.

1) The search will be limited to folders (and any sub-folders) inside the Desktop.

2) In case the file name is made of x words, the search will be done for each of 3 words. Example file "English Apple File.docx", the script will try to find the folder "English" and the folder "Apple" and the folder "File". In each case, if the folder is found, the move will be done.

Warning :  In this example the script will have an issue if the 3 folders exist because after the move from Desktop to folder "English", the file no longer exists in Desktop (then can't be moved again to folder "Apple". If you want the file to be duplicate in each of the 3 folders, we should use 'duplicate' instruction instead of 'move' in the script.

Here is the script : I added many comment to make sure you understand meaning of each line and you're able to adjust it yourself.

The trick is the use of 'mdfind' shell command to search, using spotlight engine, the folder at any level inside the desktop folder.

```
set myDesktop to path to desktop from user domain
tell application "Finder" to set FileList to every file of myDesktop whose kind is not in {"Alias", "Application"}

repeat with aFile in FileList
tell application "Finder"
    set FName to name of aFile
    set FExt to name extension of aFile
end tell
set onlyName to text 1 thru -((length of FExt) + 2) of FName -- get file name without extension
set Mywords to every word of onlyName -- extract every words of the file name

repeat with MyTarget in Mywords --loop through each word
    set TheResult to do shell script "mdfind -name " & MyTarget & " 'kind:folder' -onlyin ~/Desktop"
    if TheResult is "" then
        -- folder not found with that word
        display dialog "Folder " & MyTarget & " not found in Desktop !"
    else
        if (count of paragraph of TheResult) > 1 then
            -- there are many folders matching that word: what to do ?
            display dialog "There are " & (count of paragraph of TheResult) & " folders named " & MyTarget
        else
            -- only 1 folder match the word : lets move the file to that folder!
            set DestFolder to POSIX file ((TheResult & "/") as string)
            try
                tell application "Finder" to move aFile to DestFolder
            end try
            -- if you want to delete file from source folder after the move !!
            -- tell application "Finder" to delete aFile
        end if --if count of paragraph > 1
    end if -- if TheResult = ""
end repeat -- to next words of the file name
end repeat -- to next file in the list
```

Comment: That works great, so thanks, but there is one problem: it tries to move other folders as well. Is there a way to do it so it only moves files (not apps or folders)? Also, is there a way to only be able to move it to the sub folders of my "School" folder? Its just that I have game backups in my "Home" folder (also on my desktop), and if a save a file as "Music Assignment", it tries to move it to a "Music" folder in a game backup in my "Home" folder. Thanks

Comment: The second line of the script already restricts to only files from Desktop. Not folders ! So I do not understand why your mention that it moves folders.  I tested it, I only get files not folders. in order to restrict the destination folders to only sub-folders in folder "School", you must adjust the path in the mdfind command (line 11). Adjust the '-onlyin ~/Desktop' to '-onlyin ~/Desktop/School', if your School folder is on Desktop.

Comment: The folders it tried to move were alias's, so do they count at files? Sorry if I confused you. Thanks

Comment: I just update the second line of the script to exclude file whose kind in "Alias".

Comment: How would I add to the "alias" line to also exclude .app files?

Comment: You can add in the list another type to be excluded :  {"Alias","Application"} will exclude both alias files and application files.

Comment: Tried that already. Get this error message "Can’t make {"Alias", "Application"} into type Unicode text." I don't know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated the line completely in the first script : it should be : ....is not in {"Alias","Application"}